# How to specify atom link on chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

So I am trying to draw the following reaction with chemfig, but for the triglyceride part, I can't get the H's to the left of the C. It just switches to bonding with the H. Please and thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol{x}{-[:+30,.6]-[:-30,.6]} 
\definesubmol{y}{-O-[:30,.7](=[2,.6]O)-[:-30,.7]R} 
\chemfig{[2]H_2C([0]!y)-[,1.5]HC([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the chapter 7  "Departure and arrival atoms" of the `chemfig` manual:

> One may sometimes want the bond partners to be atoms other than those
>   determined by `chemfig`. The departure and arrival atoms can be set with
>   the optional bond argument by writing:

```
[,,〈integer 1〉,〈integer 2〉]
```

> where `〈integer 1〉`and `〈integer 2〉` are the numbers of the desired
>   departure and arrival atoms. These atoms must exist, otherwise an error message will be given

Applying this to your example, you can use `-[,1.5,2,2]` instead of `-[,1.5]` as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol{x}{-[:+30,.6]-[:-30,.6]} 
\definesubmol{y}{-O-[:30,.7](=[2,.6]O)-[:-30,.7]R} 
\chemfig{[2]H_2C([0]!y)-[,1.5,2,2]HC([0]!y)-[,1.5,2,2]H_2C([0]!y)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My sincere congratulations for your 30k. Sebastiano

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thank you. You always seem to spot thouse numbers.